# How to verify TransactionScope works with MySQL?

Tags: c#, mysql, isolation-level, read-uncommitted, system.transactions

I want to add read uncommitted isolation level.i know it is possible to do with SQL statement. but I want to try with TransactionScope and I tried but not getting any isolation statements on MySQL general logs.
Questions
1 does transactionscope class work with MySQL.
If yes then how to verify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to add read uncommitted isolation level.i know it is possible to do with SQL statement.

The "standard" way to do this would be to use the `MySqlConnection.BeginTransaction` API:

```
using (var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted))
{
    // do stuff
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

> does transactionscope class work with MySQL

Yes, MySQL Connector/NET can support `TransactionScope`, but not for distributed transactions. It's a [known issue](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70587) that Connector/NET doesn't support XA Transactions with `TransactionScope`.

If you want to use `TransactionScope`, then MySQL Connector/NET should inherit its isolation level:

```
var txOptions = new System.Transactions.TransactionOptions();
txOptions.IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted;

using(var transaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, txOptions))
using (var connection = new MySqlConnection("... connection string ..."))
{
    connection.Open();
    // ...
    transaction.Complete();
}
```

If you need to support true distributed transactions with `TransactionScope`, then switch to [MySqlConnector](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector) as your ADO.NET driver. Unlike Connector/NET, it [fully supports distributed transactions](https://mysqlconnector.net/tutorials/migrating-from-connector-net/#transactionscope).

Comment: I am sure about the first part of your answer as I am getting general log in Mysql server as `SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED` But in case of TransactionScope I am not getting any log and I do not have distributed transaction it is just select records from single table and I am using  MySql.Data package. would you please check for the logs?

Comment: @Atulya I see `SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED` `BEGIN` in the general log when I use the `TransactionScope` code I posted above. If you're not seeing this, I suggest you accept this answer, then ask a new question _with your exact code_ and we can investigate further.

Comment: OK, I can do that but please do mention your package(mysql.data) and MySQL version so that I can investigate further and post new if required.

Comment: `SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED` was with `TransactionScope` and MySql.Data (aka Connector/NET). With MySqlConnector, you will see `XA START '(guid)'` in the logs because `TransactionScope` uses distributed transactions.

Comment: Got it, but I need you DLL( MySql.Data)  version and MySQL version.

Comment: I tested with MySql.Data 8.0.11 and MySQL Server 5.7.21 on Windows x64.